# Lost everything after iPhone sync--How can I get it back?

Tags: iphone, itunes, data-synchronization

I plugged my iPhone into my computer last night and opened up iTunes.  It said I needed to sync and download the latest version. I clicked ok.  After all was done my iPhone has been set back to Decemeber.

Therefore all my photos since December are gone.  All my contacts - gone!  All my conversations on Messages and WhatsApp - gone!! This is a major issue as my iPhone is part of my work scheduling.

What has happened?  Can anyone tell me what I can do to get it back?
Also why did it do this?

Answer (score 4):

If you've backed up recently, you might want to do a full restore, which will wipe your iPhone clean and reinstall iOS. After it's done that, it will offer to restore from a backup, reinstalling all apps, calendars, email accounts, etc.
[image]

http://support.apple.com/kb/ht1414

Answer (score 2):

I lost my photos during syncing, and the only way I got them back was using [iSpirit](http://www.ithemesky.com/ispirit). It's a nifty piece of Windows-only software for accessing iPad/iPhone as if was a data storage. I am quite sure it wouldn't have been deleted, just browse through and you'll find it. Good luck.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! Thanks for your answer! Can you please add a link to the software you mention in your answer? It is always helpful to add a link to help the OP to find the right software. Thank you